# Multiple GDI Transforms for 2D Graphics in C#

Tags: c#, gdi

I'm writing a graphics app that can perform global transformations (rotate and translate) using mouse control. Does anyone have a sample showing how to implement this with the following methods:

```
MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) - set the translate/rotate offset
MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) - increment translate/rotate variables
OnPaint(Graphics graphics, float time)     - use Matrix object to do global transform
```

The problem: after rotating the graphics, when i then translate them they move according to the rotate transform. Do I need to compensate for this rotation in MouseDown and MouseMove where I'm setting the translate variable?

Comment: Very unclear.  Matrix multiplication is not commutative.  It makes a great deal of difference whether you translate first then rotate vs rotate first then translate.

Comment: That's right, Hans. So my question is "how do I achieve this?". Imagin creating a computer game where the user can wander a 2D maze. When you press a key to turn, the users' character remains stationary while the maze turns. When you press a key to move forward, again the character remains stationary (in centre of screen, say) but the 2d map moves down. I've done this already by applying trigonometry to all world objects individually. But using the Graphics Matrix seems to be a far better approach.

Comment: Did you make the rotations in the correct way? That is, translate the object to the origin, then rotate and then translate it to its original position. Because there is a thing called AXIS OF ROTATION that makes a HUGE difference

Answer (score 0):

Remember, MouseDown is only proceed once. I think in the MouseDown event, beside setting the offset you need to transform it. And also you need a variable perhaps

```
bool isMouseDown = true;
```

to help MouseMove indicate that it is in "after mouseDown" state.

And in the MouseMove event, basically you are doing the same process as in the MouseDown event, the diffrerence is only the coordinate of the mouse.